# Laravel controller construct

Tags: php, laravel

I started with laravel few days ago and I'm facing this issue:

The `NO` is never returned!

This is `Controller`, do you have any idea why?

```
  Class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) return 'NO';
    }

    public function test($id)
    {   
        return $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `Auth::check()` value

Comment: It seems that the __construct is never executed since when I do the check over the test(id) function it works.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?
Why do you want to return 'NO' value from controller's constructor (looks like bad approach to me)?

Comment: Well if the user is not logged in I want a NO to be returned

Comment: Where would you like to return 'NO' to? Display it to user?

Comment: Well wont be a return NO I will change it with a Redirect::to but first I need to know why the construct is not working ;(

Comment: Just as a general tip, constructors never return values.

Comment: related: https://laravel-news.com/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Closure as callback
        $this->beforeFilter(function(){
            if(!Auth::check()) {
                return 'no';
            }
        });

        // or register filter name
        // $this->beforeFilter('auth');
        //
        // and place this to app/filters.php
        // Route::filter('auth', function()
        // {
        //  if(!Auth::check()) {
        //      return 'no';
        //  }
        // });
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return "I'm at index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like Laravel just turned `constructors` into `filters` :D

Comment: @RobinHood And now they are called `middleware`.

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 5.x:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function(){
        if (!Auth::check()) return 'NO';
    });        
}
```